# Program Skipping Over User Input (C++)

Tags: c++

I'm currently creating a program for a class in which a user can calculate and pay for a box, the user, is trying to ship. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

float volume(float L, float W, float H);
float before(float packagevolume, float price);
float tax(float total_price);
float cost(float beforetax, float salestax);
float money(float total, float paid);
float change(float usd);

int main()
{
    float packagevolume, L, W, H, price, beforetax, salestax, total, subtotal, method, cash, card, check, usd, paid, DL, owed, cardtype, ship, shipcost, st;
    char ans = 'Y';

    cout << "Box Company\n" << endl;


    cout << "Sales Program (version 1.5)\n" << endl;


    cout << "Enter Package Dimensions (feet):\n" << endl;

    float total_price = 0.0;

    while (ans == 'y' || ans == 'Y') {
        cout << "Length ";
        cin >> L;
        cout << endl;

        cout << "Width ";
        cin >> W;
        cout << endl;

        cout << "Height ";
        cin >> H;
        cout << endl;

        packagevolume = volume(L, W, H);

        if (packagevolume < 15) {
            price = 1.50;
        }
        if (packagevolume >= 15) {
            price = 2.50;
        }
        if (packagevolume > 45) {
            price = 3.0;
        }
        if (packagevolume >= 65) {
            cout << "Package is to large to ship. Restart program.";
            return 0;
        }

        beforetax = before(packagevolume, price);

        cout << "Package Volume: " << packagevolume << " cubic feet\n";

        cout << "Shipping Cost" << "($" << price << " per cubic foot): " << setw(2) << left << "$" << setw(8) << right << beforetax << "\n" << endl;

        cout << "How would you like this package to be shipped?\n(1) Standard Shipping - (one to two weeks) - no extra price\n(2) Fast Ground - (3 to 5 buisness days) - Extra $1.50 per cubic foot\n";
        cout << "(3) Air - (One to two buisness days) - Only applies to packages under 30 cubic feet - Extra $3.00 per cubic foot" << endl;
        cout << "Enter shipping type: ";
        cin >> st;
        cout << endl;

        ship = packagevolume * st;

        shipcost = beforetax + ship;

        total_price += beforetax + shipcost;

        salestax = tax(total_price);

        total = cost(total_price, salestax);

        if (st == 1)
        {
            ship = 0.00;
            cout << "Standard Shipping: No additional cost" << endl;
        }
        if (st == 2)
        {
            ship = 1.50;
            cout << "Fast ground($1.50 per cubic foot): " << setw(2) << left << "$" << setw(8) << right << setprecision(2) << shipcost << endl;
        }
        if (st == 3)
        {
            ship = 3.00;
            cout << "Air($3.00 per cubic foot): " << setw(2) << left << "$" << setw(8) << right << setprecision(2) << shipcost << endl;
        }

        cout << "Would you like to add another package? (Y/N) ";
        cin >> ans;
        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << setw(25) << left << "Subtotal: " << setw(2) << left << "$" << setw(8) << right << setprecision(2) << fixed << total_price << "\n";

    cout << setw(25) << left << "Sales Tax(0.0775%): " << setw(2) << left << "$ " << setw(8) << right << setprecision(2) << fixed << salestax << "\n" << endl;

    cout << setw(25) << left << "Total: " << setw(2) << left << "$" << setw(8) << right << setprecision(2) << fixed << total << "\n" << endl;

    cout << "What payment will the customer be using? (1. Cash, 2. Check, 3. Card): ";
    cin >> method;
    cout << endl;

    if (method == 1) 
    {
        cout << "Enter amount given: $";

        cin >> paid;
        cout << endl;

        usd = money(total, paid);

        while(usd >= 0.00)
        {
            cout << setw(25) << left << "Amount still owed is= " << setw(2) << left << "$" << setw(8) << right << usd << endl;
            cout << "Enter amount given: $";

            cin >> paid;
            cout << endl;

            usd = money(total, paid);

            break;
        }
        
        cout << setw(25) << left << "Accepted: " << setw(2) << left << "$" << setw(8) << right << paid << endl;

        owed = change(usd);

        cout << setw(25) << left << "Change: " << setw(2) << left << "$" << setw(8) << right << owed << endl;
    }

    if (method == 2)
    {
        cout << "Enter license No: ";
        cin >> DL;
        cout << endl << setw(25) << left << "Accepted Check Payment: " << setw(2) << left << "$" << setw(8) << right << total << endl;
   
    }

    if (method == 3)
    {
        cout << endl << "Visa(V) or Mastercard(M): ";
        cin >> cardtype;
        cout << "Enter Last Four Digits of Card: ";
        cin >> card;

        while (card > 1000 && card < 9999)
        {
            cout << endl << "Accepted Credit Card Payment: $" << total << endl;
            break;
        }
        while (card < 1000)
        {
            cout << endl << "Invalid Card Number. Try again." << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
float volume(float L, float W, float H)
{
    float packagevolume = L * W * H;
    return packagevolume;
}
float before(float packagevolume, float price)
{
    float beforetax = packagevolume * price;
    return beforetax;
}
float tax(float total_price)
{
    float salestax = total_price * 0.0775;
    return salestax;
}
float cost(float total_price, float salestax)
{
    float total = total_price + salestax;
    return total;
}
float money(float total, float paid)
{
    float usd = total - paid;
    return usd;
}
float change(float usd)
{
    float owed = usd * -1;
    return owed;
}
```

I'm currently having a problem with the section of code where you select what payment you will use.

```
    cout << "What payment will the customer be using? (1. Cash, 2. Check, 3. Card): ";
    cin >> method;
    cout << endl;

    if (method == 1) 
    {
        cout << "Enter amount given: $";

        cin >> paid;
        cout << endl;

        usd = money(total, paid);

        while(usd >= 0.00)
        {
            cout << setw(25) << left << "Amount still owed is= " << setw(2) << left << "$" << setw(8) << right << usd << endl;
            cout << "Enter amount given: $";

            cin >> paid;
            cout << endl;

            usd = money(total, paid);

            break;
        }
        
        cout << setw(25) << left << "Accepted: " << setw(2) << left << "$" << setw(8) << right << paid << endl;

        owed = change(usd);

        cout << setw(25) << left << "Change: " << setw(2) << left << "$" << setw(8) << right << owed << endl;
    }

    if (method == 2)
    {
        cout << "Enter license No: ";
        cin >> DL;
        cout << endl << setw(25) << left << "Accepted Check Payment: " << setw(2) << left << "$" << setw(8) << right << total << endl;
   
    }

    if (method == 3)
    {
        cout << endl << "Visa(V) or Mastercard(M): ";
        cin >> cardtype;
        cout << "Enter Last Four Digits of Card: ";
        cin >> card;

        while (card > 1000 && card < 9999)
        {
            cout << endl << "Accepted Credit Card Payment: $" << total << endl;
            break;
        }
        while (card < 1000)
        {
            cout << endl << "Invalid Card Number. Try again." << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
```

If you select card(option 3), then enter what type of card(V or M), it will then immediately skip past the user input for the last four digits of the card, meaning it never lets you enter it, and goes right to the second if statement(invalid card number). Can someone help and care to explain why this is happening? Thanks.

Comment: Why is `cardtype` declared `float`? This might not be the issue, but it is certainly strange. You can also try initialising `card` to some pre-set number and print, what was read into it, just to check that it is skipped.

Comment: You would likely benefit from declaring variables much closer to where you use them and keeping their scope as small as possible. When they are close to the code that uses them you don't as easily lose track of the type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cardtype` is declared as a `float`.  I'm not sure what happens when you pass a letter such as `M` or `V` into that stream.

Declare `cardtype` as a `char`.